# sending outlook based email in VBScript - error (sfile as string) line?

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook

im trying to send an email from a VBScript, it will eventually be added into a currently working script as an else if (if this is possible).

im getting an error at line 23 character 32?

```
  Dim outobj, mailobj
  Dim strFileText
  Dim objFileToRead

  Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set mailobj = outobj.CreateItem(0)
  strFileText = GetText("C:\test\test 2.txt")

    With mailobj
    .To = "user@user.com"
    .Subject = "Testmail"
    .Body = strFileText
    .Display
  End With

  Set outobj = Nothing
  Set mailobj = Nothing

End Sub

Function GetText(sFile as String) As String
   Dim nSourceFile As Integer, sText As String
   nSourceFile = FreeFile
   Open sFile For Input As #nSourceFile
   sText = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
   Close
   GetText = sText
End Function
```

what do i need to add to get line 23 to work and the script to finally do what i need it to, i have copied most of this script from elsewhere due to a sincere lack of VBscripting knowledge?

Comment: The code you posted is not VBScript, line 23 does not have 32 characters, and there is no `Sub` matching the `End Sub`.

Comment: right ok then. so how would i go about creating a vbscript for sending a mail? i am completely new to this hence the poorly coded section above?

Comment: It looks like not all code was published.  What line of code exactly generates the error? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: You could [translate](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml) existing VBA code to VBScript. For file operations you'd use [`FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) methods.

Comment: the line that causes the error is the 'function gettext(sfile as string) as string'. all i want to do gentlemen is to drop this after an else if statement and get it to send an email if it satisfies the else if.

Comment: If you had taken a look at my translation HOWTO you'd know that `As <type>` isn't supported in VBScript and must be removed.

Comment: To be clear, you should replace the whole `GetText` function with [`FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) methods.

Comment: right ok i really appreciate your help, how would i change it to be a successful script? seriously i am an absolute beginner to emailing via vbscript and vbscript in general.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Using Automation to Send a Microsoft Outlook Message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161088) article. It provides a sample code and describes all the required steps for sending emails.

Comment: Note that the sample code provided there is VBA, not VBScript.

Comment: The difference is minimal. Did you try to run the code?

Comment: No need. It's obvious from the first line that it won't run as VBScript without modifications. VBScript supports neither typed nor optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: remove the `GetText` function entirely, and replace the line

```
strFileText = GetText("C:\test\test 2.txt")
```

with

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFileText = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\test\test 2.txt").ReadAll
```